# How do I share an embedded YouTube video on Pinterest?

Tags: video, youtube, pinterest

I have a website that has an embedded youtube video on it.  What I want to do is share this page on Pinterest, but I want people to be able to view the video inline on Pinterest.

If I share the video from YouTube using YouTube's share button, Pinterest will play the video inline.  But I don't want to share the YouTube page of my video, I want to share my custom page that has the video embedded on it.

Right now I have the following open graph tags defined on my page, but they don't seem to help:

```
og:url
og:title
og:description
og:image
og:type
og:video
og:video:type
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working! The key is to set your `source` query string parameter to one of youtube's preview images.  You can get the image from the url `http://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoId}/0.jpg`